# Latitude longitude API's

Tags: geocoding

I have an address database and I tried to find latitude and longitude using **google geocoding** and **yahoo API**. Is there any other popular API's or programs are there. I'm using ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm aware of at least one other geocoding system, [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).  The only major differences I've found with any of these API's is the level of detail in each.  OpenStreetMap has significantly less data, but is much easier to integrate with custom data.  Also, I think the maps produced by google are the most beatiful of the three.

Answer (score 3):

I was usually using Google Maps geocoding service over HTTP which returns you Json or XML as you like. Browse around [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html) for more information about this.

Another option may be [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/). It also provides some interesting services and client libraries.

Answer (score 2):

With both of those that you mention, if you're mass-processing them or not showing a map to the user at the time of querying the API, you're violating TOS.

A better solution to meet your needs would be something like [LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/products). I actually work at [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) where we develop it ourselves -- there's no license restrictions such as would prevent you from running even millions of addresses. In addition to returning coordinates, LiveAddress will also verify the existence of addresses and standardize them for you. This is helpful in removing duplicates and has a lot of business advantages.

If you have any further address-related questions I'll be happy to personally assist.

Answer (score 1):

You might also find [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/) useful.

Answer (score -1):

Using YQL, u can obtain a list of possible forecast
First step:
Reverse geocoding

```
SELECT woeid 
FROM geo.places 
WHERE text="##LATITUDE##, ##LONGITUDE##"
```

then apply a filter to order results by placeType. This help U to order forecast by map level accuracy (town, city, postal code, region, ....)

```
SELECT woeid 
FROM geo.places
WHERE text="##LATITUDE##, ##LONGITUDE##" | 
SORT(field="placeTypeName.code")
```

Now use simile join to get all forecasts by woeid resulted by last query and filter null results

```
SELECT channel 
FROM weather.woeid 
WHERE w in (
    SELECT woeid 
    FROM geo.places 
    WHERE text="##LATITUDE##, ##LONGITUDE##" | 
    SORT(field="placeTypeName.code")) 
AND channel.
```