# Is there any webservice or Jquery plugin to get longitude and latitude

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

Am  trying to integrate goople map api with a jquery plugin- gMap.

It looks good and simple. It needs latitude and longitude to produce dynamic maps.

So am looking for any plugin or webservice which can give me the lat and long if i pass the address , city , country.

Any info is invited!

Is there any jquery map plugin which can generate map by just giving address?

```
$("#locmap").live("click", function(){
        $('#map5').gMap(
                {
                     markers: [{ 
                     address: 'address',
                         html: "location name",
                         popup: true
                         }],
                         zoom:6
                });
        });
```

Comment: Check out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420110/latitude-longitude-apis)... possible options: Google Geocode API, OpenStreetMap api, etc.

Comment: Quote: _"Is there any jquery map plugin which can generate map by just giving address?"_  I believe this is off-topic but the Google API will generate a map with only the address as input.

Comment: Zod, are you sure that your addresses are correct in the first place? As in, do you know for sure you won't be getting back bad lat/lons because the addresses don't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gMap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/documentation.html) can use an address instead of lat/long. Just use

`$('#map').gMap({address: 'address, city, country'}, zoom:10})`

Comment: i ahve multiple location hyperlink.First time it works fine. second time also map is coming , but popup title not coming . any idea.i will edit and put code in question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Can you explain some more?

Comment: First time it works fine second time , means when i click another adderess , i get an error Error: this.lc is not a function
Source File: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/361c/maps2.api/main.js
Line: 834

Comment: This error is coming only when i use  html: "location name" if i remove it , no error !!

Comment: I think it'll work if you remove `popup:true` and leave `html: '...'`. I don't know why this is. You should report the bug to the plugin author.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some info here:
http://www.jquery4u.com/api-calls/geo-location-2-lines-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

this gives a map by passing only the address in:  http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=yemen+road,+yemen&hl=en